# ClassOptions Schema - Angular Schematics

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-schematics, angular-devkit

In the @angular-devkit/schematics [readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-devkit/schematics), I am confused on what the ClassOptions is doing.

If you add the code to a project, it will show an error because this file does not exist.

Thoughts on what this is used for + an example?

```
import { strings } from '@angular-devkit/core';
import {
  Rule, SchematicContext, SchematicsException, Tree,
  apply, branchAndMerge, mergeWith, template, url,
} from '@angular-devkit/schematics';
import { Schema as ClassOptions } from './schema';

export default function (options: ClassOptions): Rule {
  return (tree: Tree, context: SchematicContext) => {
    if (!options.name) {
      throw new SchematicsException('Option (name) is required.');
    }

    const templateSource = apply(
      url('./files'),
      [
        template({
          ...strings,
          ...options,
        }),
      ]
    );

    return branchAndMerge(mergeWith(templateSource));
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `schema` file in the example is a typescript file generated with [this function](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/tools/ts_json_schema.bzl#L60) during a [build process](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/schematics/angular/BUILD#L22) in `angular-cli`. It's a pattern used in `angular-cli` and the example won't work as it is. You can see a complete example of the source for a schematic like this in one of the official angular schematics like [service](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/tree/master/packages/schematics/angular/service).

However keep in mind `ClassOptions` is just an object that specifies the options for the Angular Schematic. It can come from anywhere and is decoupled from the schematic library. It is the [responsibility of the tooling](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/tree/master/packages/angular_devkit/schematics#tooling) to provide the options to the schematics library.

Here's a similar example using the [reference cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-devkit/schematics-cli).

Generate a simple schematic:

```
schematics blank --name=test
```

Add a path to schema file to `collection.json`:

```
{
  "$schema": "../node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/collection-schema.json",
  "schematics": {
    "test": {
      "description": "A blank schematic.",
      "factory": "./test/index#test",
      "schema": "./test/schema.json"
    }
  }
}
```

Create a `schema.json`:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema",
    "id": "MySchema",
    "title": "My Schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": "cactus"
        }
    }
}
```

The factory in `index.ts` will now get passed the default options from the `schema.json` file.

```js
import { Rule, SchematicContext, Tree } from "@angular-devkit/schematics";

// You don't have to export the function as default. You can also have more than one rule factory
// per file.
export function test(_options: any): Rule {
    return (tree: Tree, _context: SchematicContext) => {
        tree.create(_options.name || "hello", "world");
        return tree;
    };
}
```

Run the cli with defaults from `schema.json`:

```sh
schematics .:test --dry-run=false
...
CREATE /cactus (5 bytes)
```

run the cli with user defined options:

```sh
schematics .:test --name=bean--dry-run=false
...
CREATE /bean (5 bytes)
```